# How can I show when two events exist for one session in Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-4

I'm working with a client who has a couple of custom events that fire from his website when users land on certain pages. These events do show up when I go to Reports > Engagement > Events, so I know they are being populated correctly.

They're looking to set up some kind of report (or 'Exploration' I suppose) that shows when two events exist in the same session. However, if I set up an Exploration with a custom segment that 'Includes Events when: event_one AND event_two', the result is always empty despite these events having values when I go through Reports > Engagement > Events.

Is there a different way to be comparing two events in one session? They're essentially sending an event when a user has been to a specific page, and then sending another event when the user submits a form and lands on the confirmation/thanks page. They're trying to view sessions/users where both of these have been done.